# creating multiple objects of a type in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, object

I wrote some code in wich it has a class named `Cars` as below:

```
public class Cars
{
    public Cars()
    {
        string ma;
        int pe;
        Console.WriteLine("PLz put the car  name:");
        ma = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("PLz put  car no  :");
        pe = Convert.ToInt16( Console.ReadLine());
    }

}
```

Now I want to create multiple objects of it like a list or an array.
I know this code and I don't know how to use a for loop for this in case it can create multiple cars automatically

```
Cars[] car = new Cars[10];
```

or

```
List <Cars>
```

The thing is I don't know how to use them, please help me if you can.

Comment: It's very hard to learn a language from scratch with Stack Overflow or any other Q&A site. I *strongly* recommend that you get a good book which covers collections in detail.

Comment: yes i know im studying form Microsoft Visual C# 2010 Step by Step eBook by john sharp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something a bit like below, will help you. But like the guys have said, you need to start with basics, reading from books is always best.

```
namespace Cars
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Cars> carList = new List<Cars>();

            Console.WriteLine("PLz put the car  name:");
            string ma = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("PLz put  car no  :");
             int pe = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());

            carList.Add(new Cars(ma,pe));
        }



        public class Cars
        {

            string ma;
            int pe;

            public Cars(string carName, int reg)
            {
                ma = carName;
                pe = reg;

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is this:

```
Cars[] car = new Cars[10];

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    car[i] = new Cars();
}
```

or using a `List<T>`:

```
List<Cars> car = new List<Cars>();

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    car.Add(new Car());
}
```

I suggest, however, that you move the `Console` functions outside of your class, and instead have a constructor like so:

```
public Cars(string ma, int pe)
{
    // assign to properties, etc.
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot jon can you tell me how to use this list now?? how to print these things??

Comment: Public List<Cars> carList = new List<Cars>(); carList.Add(new Cars("Ford", 8222));